# How to import Dojo module whose name has dot within it?

Tags: javascript, import, dojo

I am using dojo.require to import a grid module, the problem is the module name has dot like turbo.grid.js, dojo.require("DIR.turbo.grid") will not work. How do i import it if i don't want to change the module name? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this will work without renaming the module. the module names are like the package/classname structure in java - therefore a dot isn't a valid character.
regards